# How can show dates according a period of year?

Tags: mysql

I have a table policies with date_ini and date_expired and want to show policies according the date_ini and date expired in 2015

Here is the information:

```
 |date_ini|    |date_end|
 2015-01-01    2015-06-03   Here is in the period 2015
 2014-02-03    2015-09-08   Here is in the period 2015
 2015-06-03    2016-09-08   Here is in the period 2015
 2016-01-03    2016-09-08   Here is not in the period 2015
 2015-06-03    2017-09-08   Here is in the period 2015
```

I tried this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f82f/1):

```
select * from policies where YEAR(date_ini) >= 2015 AND YEAR(date_end) <= 2015
```

And I should have this answer:

```
 |date_ini|    |date_end|
 2015-01-01    2015-06-03
 2014-02-03    2015-09-08
 2015-06-03    2016-09-08
 2015-06-03    2017-09-08
```

Please somebody can help me with this query?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are expecting that result. You are filtering on rows that have **both** a date_ini of 2015 or later and a date_end of 2015 or earlier. In other words, both fields must have a date somewhere in 2015. The only row that matches those conditions is the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "date_ini" is at least always <= to date_end, it should work:

```
select  *
from    policies
where   2015 between YEAR(date_ini) AND YEAR(date_end)
```

You can also apply this to a specific date. I'm not a mysql expert, but if you want to restrict to a month, this works too:

```
select  *
from    policies
where   '2015-01' BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date_ini, '%Y-%m')
                  AND     DATE_FORMAT(date_end, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Seems to be working..but how could be if I want for example January 2015..or may 2005? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, added new query with year+month restriction to my answer.

Comment: Thanks seems to be working for my example. +1 for your experience.